# Cross-Domain Ajax Post with SSL certificate in a WebKit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ssl, cross-domain

I need the below code to work on the site www.example.com. It defaults to a get request. I need it to do a post request.

Is there a webkit or specialized browser that would make this crossdomain posts with jsonp possible? I need the logic to be client side to avoid server overload.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://crossdomain.com',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.msg);
    },
    data: {"something": "sent"}
});
```

Oh I have a certificate for "https://crossdomain.com" added to my keychain so I would need the webkit or specialized browser to be able to support this.

Comment: How about doing this through a webkit?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I am trying to do this through a webkit.

Comment: This is possible with a CORS Proxy on any browser. https://github.com/gr2m/CORS-Proxy